# JQuery button CSS on mobile

Tags: android, jquery, html, ios, css

I'm trying to change button style when a div is either toggled on/off (http://codepen.io/arr0w/pen/QGwazY) It's working perfectly in Chrome on PC. But when if I try the codepen on either Android or iPad the color of the `.button` doesn't change when the `.div` is toggled off. Only until i click **outside** the button area.

What is wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".button").click(function() {
    if (!$(".div").is(':visible')) {
      $(".button").css('background', '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc)')
        .css('background', '-moz-linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc)').css('background', '-o-linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc)').css('background', '-ms-linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc)').css('background', 'linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc)').css('background', '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from( #0065b3), to( #009ccc)')
    };

    $(".div").stop().slideToggle(300, function() {
      if (!$(".div").is(':visible')) {
        $(".button").css('background', '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0673e0, #00b0e6)')
          .css('background', '-moz-linear-gradient(top, #0673e0, #00b0e6)').css('background', '-o-linear-gradient(top, #0673e0, #00b0e6)').css('background', '-ms-linear-gradient(top, #0673e0, #00b0e6)').css('background', 'linear-gradient(top, #0673e0, #00b0e6)').css('background', '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from( #0673e0), to( #00b0e6)')

      }
    });
  })
});
```

```css
/* Checkbox style*/

input[type="checkbox"] {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
/* Expanding Div style */

.div {
  display: block;
  height: 10%;
  width: 60%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  background: #ffff;
  border: 2px solid #003867;
  border-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  z-index: -1;
}
/* Button style */

.button {
  display: block;
  height: 10%;
  width: 60%;
  background: #34696f;
  border: 2px solid #003867;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  /*Button text*/
  color: #003867;
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 3.2em/100px Aller, sans-serif;
  /*Fancy CSS*/
  background: #0082e6;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0673e0, #00b0e6);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0673e0, #00b0e6);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0673e0, #00b0e6);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0673e0, #00b0e6);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #0673e0, #00b0e6);
  /*Borders and shadows*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 0 #004680;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 0 #004680;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 #004680;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.button:hover,
.button:active {
  background: linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc) !important;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc) !important;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc) !important;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc) !important;
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc) !important;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc) !important;
}
.button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 3.5px #002a4d;
  transform: translateY(4px);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--<a href="#" class="button">Nybygger</a>-->
<button class="button">Button</button>
<div style="display:none;" class="div" id="div">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="box1">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="box2">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="box3">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="box4">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="box5">
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive it to be the hover style you have for the button. triggering when closed on mobile its gone when you click away, removing it causes it to go back to the normal state on mobile.

You can remove the hover style for button and set to normal gradient by using media queires.

Here is the code pen link : http://codepen.io/saa93/full/JboMQE/

and the code that i have change instead of

```
.button:hover , .button:active {
 }
```

add this

```
    @media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
    .button:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc) !important;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc) !important;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc) !important;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc) !important;
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc) !important;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc) !important;
    }
    }
    .button:active {
    background: linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc) !important;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc) !important;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc) !important;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc) !important;
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc) !important;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #0065b3, #009ccc) !important;
    }
```

Hope this helps.